# Is it possible to downgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed a new version of Ubuntu (11.04), but I really hate it; version 10 was much better.

Is it possible to downgrade somehow? If so, how?

Alternatively should I just remove Ubuntu and install the old version again?

Comment: [Yes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3659/downgrade-from-one-version-to-a-previous-version), but you don't want to do this, really.

Comment: @slhck: Why not? I really hate design of it, it's very uncomfortable. I am Linux newbie, so don't really know how to change theme.

Comment: Because it might leave your system in an unstable state. You do know that you can [turn the Unity design off](http://www.virtualhelp.me/linux/324-disable-unity-on-ubuntu-1104)?

Comment: @slhck: Wow, I must say, you are GENIUS! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: A downgrade would be really painful. You could run in all kinds of trouble, from broken dependencies to broken packages because the config file is not valid anymore. If you want to downgrade do a fresh install. What you could try is to remove the new gnome (if this is what you don't like) and compile an older version for your system. Another alternative is to switch the desktop manager completely. There are a lot of alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To formalize this: **Yes, it is possible**, but no, you don't want to do that.

The main reason is that when you're upgrading, you might change configuration files with upgrade scripts. There are no downgrade scripts, so an older version of a package might not work with your configuration anymore. It's safer to reinstall and migrate your data back.

If you want to do it, Ask Ubuntu's got you covered there: [Downgrade from one version to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3659/downgrade-from-one-version-to-a-previous-version).

If you're just annoyed by the design, which is called "Unity", you can [disable it in 11.04](http://www.virtualhelp.me/linux/324-disable-unity-on-ubuntu-1104). On your login screen, select *Ubuntu Classic Desktop* instead of *Ubuntu Desktop Edition*.

[image]

Note that in future Ubuntu versions, there will be no classic desktop anymore, so you'll have to live with Unity. If you want to configure it, there are [plenty of options](https://askubuntu.com/q/29553/17529) though.

Another idea would be to install another desktop manager, like [changing to GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/q/22946/17529).

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I also wanted to ask, maybe you know what should I need to change, that I could type fast. Because when I click caps lock and then type fast, the second letter is uppercase too. For example, I want to type Windows, but if I do it fast, then it becomes WIndows. Maybe you have idea?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with you keyboard to be honest.

Comment: @slhck: It worked fine in WINdows 7 for sure.

Comment: ... Caps *Lock* sticks for too long?

Answer (score 3):

I used so-called "apt-pinning" in my case to downgrade from mixed-version Ubuntu to lucid:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/downgrade-to-lucid
Package: *
Pin: release a=lucid
Pin-Priority: 1010

Package: *
Pin: release a=lucid-updates
Pin-Priority: 1011

Package: *
Pin: release a=lucid-security
Pin-Priority: 1012
```

More details: http://blog.aplikacja.info/2012/08/downgrade-ubuntudebian-using-apt-preferences/

Comment: Great answer! You should copy some more of the relevant information from the article since the blog can go down eventually, but please do keep citing them.